# vscode debugger not launching on --inspect

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging

Until today was able to debug node applications by specifying --inspect.
I have the following in my settings.json:

```
"debug.javascript.autoAttachFilter": "onlyWithFlag",
```

VScode used to launch the debugger automatically. However something has changed. The debugger is no longer launched. Instead I see the following in my terminal:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/3aa0a14a-5309-475b-8860-66fec7217763
```

What's interesting is when I run vscode on wsl (ubuntu), then the debugger is launched correctly. Same installation, same workspace.

Comment: I am also getting this issue - same setup has been working fine for months till a few days ago...